# How to write an equation where both independent variables and dependent variables are log transformed in a multiple regression?

Tags: analysis, linear-transformations, transformation, regression, regression-analysis

How to write the multiple regression model when both the dependent variable and independent variables are log-transformed?

I know that without any log transformation the linear regression model would be written as [image]

But now I have transformed both my dependent variables and independent variable with log. So is correct to write as [image]

Or since I am transforming both sides of question so can I write it as [image]

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that all your transformed forms are false.

Starting from

$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1(x_1)+\beta_2(x_2)+...$$

you can write :$$\ln(y)=\ln\bigg(\beta_0+\beta_1(x_1)+\beta_2(x_2)+...\bigg)$$
This is not equivalent to $\beta_0+\beta_1(\ln(x_1))+\beta_2(\ln(x_2))+...$

Also you can change of variables :
$$X_1=e^{x_1}\quad;\quad X_2=e^{x_2}\quad,...$$
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1\ln(X_1)+\beta_2\ln(X_2)+...$$
And with the change of :
$$Y=e^y$$
$$\ln(Y)=\beta_0+\beta_1\ln(X_1)+\beta_2\ln(X_2)+...$$
Sorry if I misunderstood your question.